# Calling delete upon a conditional call to new

Tags: c++, delete-operator

Suppose I have the following class:

```
foo{
    ~foo();

    private:
        char *bar;
};
```

Under certain conditions bar will create a new char array so what would be the correct way to handle the deletion of it? Would a simple bool do or would that be considered bad practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`delete`ing a null pointer is safe. That's why you should always set your pointer to `NULL` or `nullptr` when not in use:

```
struct foo{
    foo() : bar(NULL) {}
        //  ^ Initialize bar to NULL

    ~foo() {
       delete bar;
    }

    void some_method() {
        bar = new char;
        ...
        delete bar;
        bar = NULL;  // Immediately set bar back to NULL
    }

    private:
        char *bar;
};
```

Please note that when you set a pointer to the one returned by `new`, you must match it with `delete`, while if you set it using the pointer returned by `new[]`, be sure to use `delete[]` on it.

Anyway, if you have access to C++11 smart pointers `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`, then they are your best bet.

Comment: Suppose I want to do this to a 2D-array how would you set the second element to NULL?

Comment: @DavidS, if you need an array, why don't you use `std::vector`?

Comment: @DavidS [I don't know why I did this... but NP.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=928e9a3b0c9929aa0fb43b50dc1e9c7b-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba)

Comment: @DenisNovikov Using a 2d array to map a value to each pixel on the screen when the program starts up, also from my understanding vectors are slightly slower so that's why I opted for array.

Comment: @DavidS, as I can see from the example below, `std::vector` has slower construction/destruction, but not data access. If you do not need to often create/destroy array, `std::vector` would not be slower, but it can be safer to use it.
Example: http://ideone.com/cUOlpp

Answer (score 7):

If `bar` is nullptr, then you can safely call delete on it:

```
bar = nullptr;
delete bar;
```

so you don't need to test, just delete.

> 3.7.4.2/3:
>
> The value of the ﬁrst argument supplied to a deallocation function may be a null pointer value; if so, and if the deallocation function is one supplied in the standard library, the call has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `bar` to `nullptr`/`NULL` ([c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)/[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)), You can delete it without any checks in the destructor.

Your class definition will contain `char *bar=nullptr;`.